# Pagination in JavaScript generated HTML page - not for the faint of heart

Tags: javascript, html

I am working with some legacy (circa 2003) javascript and html code and need some help paginating the html output that the following code generates.

To see this in action - visit the [site](http://bendelcorp.com/toolscalculators.html) and click on the Capacity tab. Enter values in each of the fields and click on the Capacity Chart button. The bigger the numbers the larger the output. I would like to be able to paginate this output with say 30 rows to a page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, this currently works best in IE, Google Chrome and Safari - there is an issue with Firefox that I am working out separately.

Thanks.

```
function CapacityChart()
{
    if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion) >= 4)
    {
        var htmlcode = '';
        var RUnits = Math.abs(document.all.Capacity.RUnits.value);
        var LUnits = Math.abs(document.all.Capacity.LUnits.value);
        var HUnits = Math.abs(document.all.Capacity.HUnits.value);
        var radius = Math.abs(document.all.Capacity.VesRadius.value);
        var height = Math.abs(document.all.Capacity.LiqHeight.value);
        var length = Math.abs(document.all.Capacity.VesLength.value);
        var units = eval(document.Capacity.RUnits.value);
        var VUnits = Math.abs(document.all.Capacity.VUnits.value);
        var capacity;
        var unitlabel;
        var divisor = 1;
        var i;

        //* Convert Height unit to inches
        switch (document.all.Capacity.HUnits.selectedIndex){
        case 0:
              height = eval(height * 12)
              unitlabel = 'Inches';
              break;
        case 1:
              unitlabel = 'Inches';
              break;
        }

        //* Convert RUnits to inches
        switch (document.all.Capacity.RUnits.selectedIndex){
        case 0:
          radius = eval(radius * 12)
          unitlabel = 'Inches';
          break;
        case 1:
              unitlabel = 'Inches';
          break;
        }

        //* Convert LUnits to inches
        switch (document.all.Capacity.LUnits.selectedIndex){
        case 0:
              length = eval(length * 12);
              unitlabel = 'Inches';
              break;
        case 1:
              unitlabel = 'Inches';
              break;
        }

        if(length > 0 && radius > 0){

              s ='<HTML><HEAD><LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="bendelcorp.css"><SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript" SRC="js/bendelcorp.js" TYPE="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT"></SCRIPT></HEAD><BODY>';
              s += '<TABLE>';
              s += '<TR><TD ALIGN="left" VALIGN="top" ROWSPAN="5"><IMG SRC="images/logo.png" ALT="logo" WIDTH="210" HEIGHT="118"></TD></TR><BR>';
              s += '</TABLE><BR>';
              s += '<SPAN CLASS="heading1">Capacity Chart</SPAN><BR><HR>';
              s += '<TABLE ALIGN="center" WIDTH="80%"';
              s += '<TR><TD ALIGN="left" VALIGN="top" COLSPAN="2">Inside dimensions</TD></TR>';
              s += '<TR><TD ALIGN="right" VALIGN="top" ROWSPAN="5"><IMG SRC="images/tools_capacity.jpg" ALT="" WIDTH="172" HEIGHT="139"></TD><TD>Length: ' + document.all.VesLength.value + '&nbsp;' + document.all.LUnits.options[document.all.LUnits.selectedIndex].text + '</TD></TR>';
              s += '<TR><TD>Radius: ' + document.all.Capacity.VesRadius.value + '&nbsp;' + document.all.LUnits.options[document.all.RUnits.selectedIndex].text + '</TD></TR>';
              s += '<TR><TD>Height: (See Below) </TD></TR>';
              s += '<TR><TD>&nbsp;</TD></TR>';
              s += '<TR><TD>Volume: (See below) </TD></TR>';
              s += '</TABLE>';
              s += '<BR CLEAR="all"><HR>';
              s += '<TABLE WIDTH="420" BORDER="1" CELLPADDING="2" CELLSPACING="0" ALIGN="center"';
              s += '<TR><TD ALIGN="middle">Height (' + unitlabel + ')</TD><TD ALIGN="middle">Volume (' + document.Capacity.VUnits.options[document.Capacity.VUnits.selectedIndex].text + ')</TD></TR>';

              for(i = 1; i <= (2 * radius); i++){
                    height = i;
                    //* alert('H:' + height + ' R:' + radius + 'L:' + length);
                    if (height  > (radius * 2)){
                          height = 2 * (radius)
                          height = Math.round(height * 10)/10;
                          capacity = length * (Math.pow(radius,2) * Math.PI);
                    }
                    if (height == (2 * radius))
                    {
                          capacity = length * (Math.pow(radius,2) * Math.PI);
                    }
                    if (height > radius)
                    {
                          capacity = length * (Math.pow(radius,2) * Math.PI) - (length* Math.pow(radius,2)/2 * (2 * Math.acos((radius - ((2 * radius) - height))/radius) - Math.sin(2 * Math.acos((radius - ((2 * radius) - height))/radius))));
                    }
                    if (height == radius)
                    {
                          capacity = length * (Math.pow(radius,2) * Math.PI)/2;
                    }
                    if (height < radius)
                    {
                          capacity = length * Math.pow(radius,2)/2 * (2 * Math.acos((radius - height)/radius) - Math.sin(2 * Math.acos((radius - height)/radius)));
                    }

                    //* Convert capacity into selected units
                    switch (document.all.Capacity.VUnits.selectedIndex){
                    case 0:
                          capacity = eval(capacity /1728 );
                          break;
                    case 1:
                          break;
                    case 2:
                          capacity = eval(capacity * .0000163871527);
                          break;
                    case 3:
                          capacity = eval(capacity * 16.387064);
                          break;
                    case 4:
                          capacity = eval(capacity *  .016387064);
                          break;
                    case 5:
                          capacity = eval(capacity * 0.0043290040509);
                          break;
                    case 6:
                          capacity = eval(capacity * .000137428819);
                          break;
                    case 7:
                          capacity = eval(capacity * .000103071759);
                          break;
                    }

                    s += '<TR><TD ALIGN="middle">' + height + '</TD><TD ALIGN="middle">' + Math.round(capacity * 10)/10 + '</TD></TR>';
              }

              s += '</TABLE><BR CLEAR="all"><HR><TABLE ALIGN="center"';
              s += '</TABLE></BODY></HTML>';
              CapacityWindow = window.open('','CapacityWindow', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,menubar=0,width=0,height=0');
              CapacityWindow.close();
              CapacityWindow = window.open('','CapacityWindow', 'toolbar,scrollbars,menubar,width=480,height=600');
              CapacityWindow.document.write(s);
        } else {
              alert('Length and radius of vessel must be greater than 0.');
        }
  } else {
        alert('This capability is only available with internet browsers that support JavaScript.')
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the title / code combination, it made my day :) But there is more! The unfinished sentence, "this works best in", promises more goodness. Let me guess: Works best in Netscape 4? :)

Comment: I don't really see what you mean by "output" though. The only thing I can see is the form, and that is already paginated isn't it?

Comment: Don't laugh. I said up front this was legacy code and I am trying to work with it. And yes I hit the submit too quick, but edited the entry to finish it off. Go easy, after all this is Christmas eve.

Comment: Pekka, by output I mean the popup page that is generated when you click on the Capacity Chart button. Thanks.

Comment: Please replace tabs by 4 or 2 spaces to make it more readable.

Comment: Should be more readable now. Not sure if I have the indentation convention for switch statements correct. Spoiled by IDEs I guess ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should check out the [YUI Datatable with Paginator](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_clientpagination.html).

It has a good API for generating the model to be held within the data table, and the paginator is quite a simple option to place on top of that. It's an extra dependency but it is cross-platform and I've always found the documentation to be good. As far as I know it operates pretty well with your own CSS too.

Comment: There is a link in the second paragraph.

Comment: Grundlefleck, thanks for the reference to the YUI Datatable and Paginator.